# How to evaluate interaction term in Hamiltonian?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, interactions

If one has an interaction term in the Hamiltonian of a system as follows:$$
\sum_{\vec{q}}V(\vec{q}) \psi(\vec{k}-\vec{q})
$$
where $\psi(\vec{k}-\vec{q})$ and $V(\vec{q})$ is the wave function and interaction term in momentum-space.

My question is how does one best evaluate this summation. I understand one way would be to be a summation continuation to an integral of $d\vec{q}$ over all space $(-\infty,\infty)$. However, in terms of the $k$-space I would only be interested in the region over the first Brillouin zone. Would this directly change this integration/summation in such a case and if so how would I evaluate the expression in this case as it depends on $dq$ not $dk$ in the integration

Answer (score 2):

To sum up over first BZ given you have interaction kernel $V(q)$ you may go through the following steps:

- Transform integral form $\int \frac{dk^d}{(2\pi)^d} f(k) $ to discrete form $\sum\limits_{k_i} \frac{(\Delta k_i)^d}{(2\pi)^d} f(k_i)$. Here $k_i$ are the k-points which you use for summation. $(\Delta k_i)^d$ is volume of one cell in your mesh grid (it includes jacobian if lattice is not rectangular).
- Depending of what you define as input, calculate prefactor before the summation (it can depend e.g. from the dimensionless parameter defining the smallness of k-grid step)
- Next, to calculate the sum you should have your $\psi(k)$ (e.g. solutions of hamiltonian without interaction). To perform sum like $interaction = \sum V(k-q) \psi(k) $ you may fill the matrix $V_{kk'}$ with elements such that $V_{kk'} = V(k-k')$. Then the sum will be represented as a matrix multiplication $interaction_k = \hat{V}_{kk'} \cdot \psi_{k'}$. At this step matrix $\hat{V}_{kk'}$ includes prefactor from step 2.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: wouldn't the sum at the end still be a sum over k'?

Comment: in matrix multiplication the sum is inherent (vector of rows times column gives vector)